# Eclipse plugin project explorer context menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

This is part of plugin.xml working context menu for PackageExplorer now I wanted it for ProjecExplorer, so I tried rewrite it to ProjectExplorer but It doesn't work .. I searched the web and found that are problem with that, but I couldn't find working solution. Does anybony experience how to fix do it?

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
      <command commandId="app.LoadXml"
        label="Load plan" style="push" mnemonic="L">
         <visibleWhen>
                <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                    <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.xml" />
                        </adapt>
                    </iterate>
                </with>
         </visibleWhen>
      </command>
    </menuContribution>
  </extension>
```

My not working solution - renamed PackageExploer to ProjectExplorer => now context menu.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectExplorer">
      <command commandId="app.LoadXml"
        label="Load plan" style="push" mnemonic="L">
         <visibleWhen>
                <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                    <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.xml" />
                        </adapt>
                    </iterate>
                </with>
         </visibleWhen>
      </command>
    </menuContribution>
  </extension>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

location URI used in the second part is wrong.

<strike>locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectExplorer"</strike>

Check [here](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2008/08/info-eclipse-view-and-perspective-ids.html)

```
Project Explorer      org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer

Projects              org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectsView
```