# How to create an eclipse plugin which should give additional option in the project explorer right click menu New -> Customized class

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to create an eclipse plugin which should give additional option in project explorer right click menu New -> Customized class where I want to generate a java class with some standard codes. I couldn't find relevant tutorials through web. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deal with eclipse's extension points and extensions. If you are not familar with those concepts, a good tutorial can be found here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html

A similar question to yours can be found on stack overflow with an example of a working extension: [Eclipse plugin project explorer context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482716/eclipse-plugin-project-explorer-context-menu)