# EclipseRCP, Add Context Menu Item for project

Tags: eclipse, rcp

in my custom RCP plugin, I want to add a context menu with command to the project view.
So when I right click the project, then the new context menu item should be shown.

But I do not know how to achieve this, via adding an extension point to plugin.xml?

[image]

```
 <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
              <command commandId="com.itemis.test.MyOpenCommand"
                label="Open My" style="push" tooltip="Open My Editor.">
        </command>
</menuContribution>
```

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command id="com.itemis.test.MyOpenCommand" name="Open My"
            description="Open My Editor.">
    </command>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler commandId="com.itemis.test.MyOpenCommand"
            class="com.itemis.test.MyOpenHandler">
    </handler>
</extension>

package com.itemis.test;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;

public class MyOpenHandler extends AbstractHandler {

   @Override
   public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: What "project view"? Do you mean the existing Eclipse Project Explorer or some view of your own? Are you doing an e4 RCP or a traditional 3.x compatability mode RCP? You need to provide a lot more info.

Comment: Its the existing Eclipse Project Explorer, see above and its a 3.x compatibility mode RCP application.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23482716/2670892) answer the question (but sure to check the answer for the correct ids)

Comment: Yes but the above does not work for me. The menu item was not shown.

Comment: Works fine testing here. The menu item would not be shown if there was some problem finding the command or handler.

Comment: Note: The image you show is "Package Explorer" **not** "Project Explorer" - different views with different ids.

Comment: yes works fine, has to start with clean, the changes are not recognized.
But I only get the menu item shown when the selected item is a JavaProject.

     `<visibleWhen>
         <iterate>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject"/>
     </iterate>
    </visibleWhen>`